# Encode MP3 Files "-aq 0" Setting

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, audio-streaming

If I use FFmpeg to encode an MP3 file, I read the documantation that I can use `-aq 0` for best quality, but I don't understand what will it do actually? Increasing the audio bitrate (highest bitrate = best quality)? How can it create the best file? Do I still need to specify the bitrate then?

Answer (score 0):

`-aq` is an an alias for `-qscale:a` and it invokes the VBR mode for audio codecs that support VBR. The scale for MP3 (LAME encoder) runs from `0` to `10` with `0` being best quality. You don't need to specify the bitrate.

Comment: I tried to use -aq 0, but the output MP3 file is 320kbps constant bitrate, not VBR.